# move records from one table to another

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables - `posts` and `parchive` with the same structure, and want to move records from one table to the other.

`id` column is primary key - autoincrement.

```
insert into posts select * from parchive where id...
```

Error:

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '70' for key 'PRIMARY'...

Second try:

```
insert into posts select date, title, subtitle, intro, story, img, tags,...
```

Everything is selected except `id`.

Error:

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count

Any help?

Comment: `insert into posts (date, title, subtitle, intro, story, img, tags,...) select date, title, subtitle, intro, story, img, tags,...` should work fine. I wonder, though, why you are ending up with a duplicate unique index error. [You can find the syntax for mysql's INSERT statement here if you want to RTFM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html)

Comment: @JNevill, it works, maybe you should post the comment as answer.

Comment: Awesomesauce! I'm glad it worked. I have added it as an answer and elaborated a bit to make it more answer-ish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment above. If you are only going to insert data into particular fields, then you must specify those fields after the table:

```
insert into posts (date, title, subtitle, intro, story, img, tags,...) select date, title, subtitle, intro, story, img, tags,...
```

I think it might worth exploring why you are getting a duplicate unique key error though when inserting the ID. If your ID is autogenerated in your main table, it would make sense to not autogenerate in your archive table so the id's match up.